# Why Scala Sets of different size produce Iterator ordered differently?

Tags: scala, collections, iterator, set

Some one can explain to how it's works and why?

```
val xs1 = Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val ys1 = Set(7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3)
xs1 sameElements ys1 // true

val xt1 = Set(1, 2, 3)
val yt1 = Set(3, 2, 1)
xt1 sameElements yt1 // false
```

Other question, if this behavior violates the api contract of Set?

Comment: Except for `SortedSet` there is no ordering assumption on `Set` and its operations

Comment: tl;dr don't use `sameElements` for Sets; use `==`